# How to get key based on value from a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is an example of a nested array I'm working with. The "keys" representing locations are 720, and 715. The nested array values are services at said locations.

As you can tell from the values some are duplicated, and some are unique. I want to be able to take a single value or array such as 4512, 1110, 685 and then look up the relevant key.

So 4512 would return 720.

Done so far is:
1) Generated what I believe is a properly formatted array
2) Retrieved intersected values within nested arrays

Problem Summary:
How to get the key from one of the values. I'm sorry but I tried array_search() without any luck.

Any help is appreciated, i'm still learning about arrays. Thanks.

```
array(
    2
)
    {
    [720] => array(
        4
    )
        {
        [0] => int(4512) [1] => int(1110) [2] => int(1803) [3] => int(669)
        }

    [715] => array(
        3
    )
        {
        [0] => int(1803) [1] => int(685) [2] => int(669)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have code that you have already tried?

Comment: Should `669` return both `720` and `715` or...?

Comment: Sorry, my problem was a bit too vague. I'd only do a key lookup when the value is unique to both arrays in this case. I wouldn't be dealing with a large set of data, 2-4 arrays max.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52452666/6243352), if you have a large structure or plan on doing many queries, a linear search through the array inspecting each element on every search is an expensive and unnecessary operation. If you use the PHP function `array_flip()`, you can invert keys and values and index right into the array in constant time (meaning *instantly* regardless of how big your array is, if you haven't studied [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) just yet).

One snag: `array_flip()` doesn't work when the input array's values aren't hashable types, as is the case here. So we write our own `array_flip()` that turns array values into keys.

I'm assuming any duplicate values should produce an array of the keys that map to them in the flipped array. Changing that policy to take the last or first key results in less code, if desired.

```
function flip($arr) {
    $flipped = [];

    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $e) {
            if (!array_key_exists($e, $flipped)) {
                $flipped[$e] = $k;
            }
            else {
                if (is_array($flipped[$e])) {
                    $flipped[$e][] = $k;
                }
                else {
                    $flipped[$e] = [$flipped[$e], $k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $flipped;
}

function find($needle, $haystack) {
    return array_key_exists($needle, $haystack) ? $haystack[$needle] : false;
}

$arr = [
  720 => [4512, 1110, 1803, 669],
  715 => [1803, 685, 669]
];
$flipped = flip($arr);

echo "the flipped array: \n";
print_r($flipped);

echo "\n\nsearching for 1803: \n";
print_r(find(1803, $flipped));
echo "\n\n";

echo "searching for 1: \n";
print_r(find(1, $flipped));
echo "\n\n";

echo "searching for 4512: \n";
print_r(find(4512, $flipped));
echo "\n\n";
```

Output:

```
the flipped array: 
Array
(
    [4512] => 720
    [1110] => 720
    [1803] => Array
        (
            [0] => 720
            [1] => 715
        )

    [669] => Array
        (
            [0] => 720
            [1] => 715
        )

    [685] => 715
)


searching for 1803: 
Array
(
    [0] => 720
    [1] => 715
)


searching for 1: 


searching for 4512: 
720
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/repls/CostlyMoccasinMatch)

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy example and answer. I wasn't clear in my explanation, the lookup would be for unique values only, not duplicates. The idea being that unique values I could output something like "Hey this service is only available at this location (key value). I will work on this - btw, i only have a faint idea of what you mean by hashable types. I have a general idea of hash tables, but not how it applies to data types. If you have time, i'd welcome your commentary!

Comment: I see. This current code works for that; if you make a query and get an array, you didn't get a unique value and your caller can treat it as false. Later, if you change your mind and decide you want to use the array, you can, but removing that part is simple enough. Hashable means a type that is a valid key in an array like a `string` or `int`--PHP arrays are hashes. Let me know if you have a specific update you want me to do with this code, with clear input/output and how you plan to use it. Until then, I'll stand by this as acceptable for the use case you're describing.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to search through that structure as-is is going to waste a lot of time since *all* of the entries need to be examined every time, but if you invert it it can be made much more efficient by leveraging PHP's array indexes for a direct lookup. eg:

```
$arr = [
  4512 => 720,
  1110 => 720,
  1803 => 715
];

echo $arr[4512]; // 720
```

Even creating a simple index like this in parallel to the main data structure will allow you to benefit from it.

Comment: Incredible, I had no idea you could flip an array. I think I've used it once, but forgot about that function. It makes total sense this approach, thank you.